# Check for empty pandas dataframe in python dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am trying to check whether the dictionary having multiple `key:value` pairs of dataframes contains any dataframe with empty rows or dataframe doesn't exist in dictionary which should be there while saving in dictionary earlier.
I have tried this but no luck

```
if __name__=="__main__":
   
   # dict contains {a:df1, b:df2}
   if [bool(v) for (k, v) in dict.items()] == False :
      print('No data available')
   sys.exit()
   else:
   # DO SOMETHING WITH DATA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.empty`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.empty.html) with `any` for test if at least one `DataFrame` is empty:

```
dict1 = {'a': pd.DataFrame(), 'b':pd.DataFrame([5])}

print ([v.empty for (k, v) in dict1.items()])
[True, False]

if any(v.empty for (k, v) in dict1.items()):
    print('No data available')
    No data available
```

---

```
dict1 = {'a': pd.DataFrame([2]), 'b':pd.DataFrame([1])}

print ([v.empty for (k, v) in dict1.items()])
[False, False]

if any(v.empty for (k, v) in dict1.items()):
    print('No data available')
```

---

```
dict1 = {'a': pd.DataFrame(), 'b':pd.DataFrame()}

print ([v.empty for (k, v) in dict1.items()])
[True, True]

if any(v.empty for (k, v) in dict1.items()):
    print('No data available')
    No data available
```

EDIT: For test some keys is possible use `set` - order of values is not important:

```
dict1 = {'a': pd.DataFrame(), 'b':pd.DataFrame()}

L = ['c','a','b']

if (set(dict1.keys()) != set(L)):
    print('missing some key!')
    missing some key!
    
dict1 = {'a': pd.DataFrame(), 'b':pd.DataFrame(), 'c': pd.DataFrame()}

L = ['c','a','b']

if (set(dict1.keys()) != set(L)):
    print('missing some key!')
```

EDIT1: For combine both conditions use `or`:

```
if (set(dict1.keys()) != set(L)) or any(v.empty for (k, v) in dict1.items()):
    print('missing some key or some empty df!')
```

Comment: what if dataframe of particular key is not present in dict? can we put the flag for same in this?

Comment: @martian_rover - can you give me some example? Be fre use some sample data from answer.

Comment: like `a` key: value pair is missing totally from dict though it should be there

Comment: @martian_rover - hmmm, how you check if missing or not? Do you have some list of all possilble keys?

Comment: @martian_rover - like `L = ['a','b','c']` for dict in answer?

Comment: yes i have list of all possible keys

Comment: @martian_rover - Answer was edited.

Comment: @martian_rover - Answer was edited.